# PySimpleGUI issues | attach multiple windows together and buttons not working correctly

Tags: python, pysimplegui

issue 1: My program has 2 windows, one bordeless window for the background and the other for the buttons, but if i go to another program while mine is open, my buttons stay on screen, i need to attach both of my windows so i can minimize the entire program.

issue 2: i created some buttons, but they only work when if i press on their text.

there is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlack')
def resource_path(relative_path):
    bundle_dir = getattr(
        sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(bundle_dir, relative_path))
def title_bar(title, text_color, background_color):

    bc = background_color
    tc = text_color
    font = 'ConsolasBlack 15'
    return [sg.Col([[sg.T(title, text_color=tc, background_color=bc, font=font, grab=True)]], pad=(0, 0), background_color=bc),
        sg.Col([[sg.T('─', text_color='white', background_color=bc, enable_events=True, font=font, key='-MINIMIZE-'), sg.Text('❎', text_color='white', background_color=bc, font=font, enable_events=True, key='Exit')]], element_justification='r', key='-C-', grab=True,
               pad=(0, 0), background_color=bc)]
sg.Window._move_all_windows = True
gifpath=resource_path("media/079.gif")
image = sg.Image(gifpath, background_color='black',pad=(0, 0))
    
botones= [[sg.Button('CREDITS', button_color=('white', 'black'),pad=((0,0),(10,0)))],
              [sg.Button('MUTE', button_color=('white', 'black'),pad=((0,0),(70,0))),sg.Button('PAUSE', button_color=('white', 'black'),pad=((422,0),(70,0)))],
              [sg.Button('UNMUTE', button_color=('white', 'black'),pad=((0,0),(50,10))),sg.Button('UNPAUSE', button_color=('white', 'black'),pad=((382,0),(50,0)))]]


background_layout=[title_bar('SCP-079 v0.4a                                                           ', sg.theme_text_color(), sg.theme_background_color()),[image]]
buttonsLayout=botones
window_background = sg.Window('', background_layout, finalize=True, no_titlebar=True, margins=(0, 0), element_padding=(0,0))
top_window = sg.Window('SCP-079', buttonsLayout,size=(540,360), icon=resource_path("media/079.ico"), grab_anywhere=False, finalize=True, keep_on_top=True, no_titlebar=True,  transparent_color=sg.theme_background_color())
# window_background.send_to_back()
# top_window.bring_to_front()
while True:
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows(timeout=100)
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break
    # if event =='Mute':
    #     mute()
    # if event =='Unmute':
    #     unmute()
    # if event =='Listen':
    #     unpauselisten()
    # if event =='Listen':
    #     pauselisten()
    # if event =='Credits':
    #     popup_showinfo()
    # if event =='Hide':
    #     sysTray()
    image.update_animation_no_buffering(image.Filename, 100)
top_window.close()
window_background.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons stay on screen because you set option `keep_on_top=True`, so your window is on top of all windows.

Remove option `keep_on_top=True`, add following code after window finalized (not tested).

```py
top_window.TKroot.transient(window_background.TKroot)
top_window.TKroot.grab_set()
```

> Buttons only work when if i press on their text.

IMO, It is caused by transparency color you defined, try to change the background color of button to other color, like 'grey'.